# Detect angle of text in image with horizontal and rotate in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, text-rotation

See the image below :

[image]

As you can seen in the image the written text in rotated by 90 deg angle and I want to rotate only the text to be horizontal. By what ever angle it is rotated I want to make it horizontal as in below :

[image]

I don't want the complete image to the rotated. I want that the text only is bounded and the angle by which the text is rotated is measured and then rotated by that angle to make it horizontal.

Can you suggest me a way to do so and then fit an ellipse onto the text ?

Thank you.

Comment: Similar task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227347/how-can-i-detect-the-dimensions-of-an-object-under-an-angle-in-this-picture-in-m/32228759#32228759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's find x-y coordinates of all the dark pixels

```
bw = imread('http://i.imgur.com/0LxC6bd.png');
bw = min( bw, [], 3 ) < 50 ; % dark pixels - intensity lower than 50
[y x] = find( bw ); % note that find returns row-col coordinates.
```

Compute the covariance matrix of the text coordinates

```
mx = mean(x);
my = mean(y);
C = [ mean( (x-mx).^2 ),     mean( (x-mx).*(y-my) );...
      mean( (x-mx).*(y-my) ) mean( (y-my).^2 ) ];
```

---

You can get the orientation of the ellipse from the eigen vectors and eigen values of `C`:

```
[V D] = eig( C );
figure; imshow( bw ); hold on;
quiver( mx([1 1]), my([1 1]), (V(1,:)*D), (V(2,:)*D), .05 );
```

Looking at the eigenvectors and eigen values:

```
V =
-0.9979   -0.0643
-0.0643    0.9979

D = 
1.0e+003 *
0.1001         0
     0    1.3652
```

You can see that the eigen-vectors (columns of `V`) are approximately the pointing to the `-X` direction (first column) and the `Y` direction (second column). Examining the eigen values (diagonal of `D`) you can see that the second eigen value is much larger than the first - this is the major axis of your ellipse. Now you can recover the orientation of the ellipse:

```
[~, mxi] = max(diag(D)); % find major axis index: largest eigen-value
```

Recover the angle from the corresponding eigen-vector

```
or = atan2( V(2,mxi), V(1,mxi) ) * 180/pi ; % convert to degrees for readability
or =
93.6869
```

As you can see the major axis of the ellipse is almost 90deg off the horizon.
You can rotate the image back

```
imrotate( bw, -or );
```

[image]

---

Drawing an ellipse given the covariance matrix:

```
th = linspace(0, 2*pi, 500 );
xy = [cos(th);sin(th)];
RR = chol( C ); % cholesky decomposition
exy = xy'*RR; %//'
figure;imshow( bw ); hold on;
plot( 2*exy(:,1)+mx, 2*exy(:,2)+my, 'r', 'LineWidth', 2 );
```

[image]

Comment: I understood most of it but is there a function 'quiever' in MATLAB, I am using MATLAB R2012b, I didn't find any function like that, I get something like 'quiver'

http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html

Comment: @Ritz my typo - corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Sir,

I used your code and assembled it together http://pastebin.com/aPVzQEdp

But I didn't get the required output : http://imgur.com/TjFK2lq

Comment: @Ritz, by putting all the code together and not seperating it into functions/blocks you ran over the stored value of `mx` - the mean of `x` coordinates (in the function `[mx mxi] = max( diag(D) );`. restore the valus of `mx` and you should be fine.

Comment: I am now getting the ellipse perfectly but, I am still not getting the rotated text. Can you please divide them into modules and mail the .m files to me seperately.

My mail id is firunscall@gmail.com

Comment: @Ritz the code is already diveded into modules. Use `r = imrotate(bw, -or);` to get the rotated image in variable `r`. `figure;imshow(r);` will display the rotated image.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution:

```
bw = im2;
bw = sum((1-im2).^2, 3) > .5; 
%bw = min( bw, [], 3 ) < 50 ; % dark pixels - intensity lower than 50
[y x] = find( bw ); % note that find returns row-col coordinates.

mx = mean(x);
my = mean(y);
C = [ mean( (x-mx).^2 ),     mean( (x-mx).*(y-my) );...  
      mean( (x-mx).*(y-my) ) mean( (y-my).^2 ) ];
[V D] = eig( C );

quiver( mx([1 1]), my([1 1]), (V(1,:)*D), (V(2,:)*D), .05 );
[~,mxi] = max(diag(D)); % find major axis index: largest eigen-value
or = atan2( V(2,mxi), V(1,mxi) ) * 180/pi ; % convert to degrees for readability
rotate = imrotate( im2, or-180 );

axes(handles.axes2);

imshow( rotate );  
set(handles.text3, 'String',or-180);
```

[image: screen shot]