# How can I detect the dimensions of an object under an angle in this picture in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I have this image of a battery:

[image]

I would like to determine the dimensions of the battery (in pixels).
The problem I have is that the battery is rotated by an unknown angle.
How can I detect the dimensions of this rotated battery?

I was thinking of these algorithmic steps:

- First, I would have to convert this image to a black and white image (thresholding).
- After that, I would have to find a center point and draw a rectangle in the white pixels.
- Then, I have to turn the rectangle 360 degrees and locate the position of the rectangle (and so the dimensions).

I am somewhat inexperienced, and I would appreciate some guidance as to how to implement these algorithmic stages in Matlab.

Thanks

Comment: Delete the question. Read some image processing code in Matlab. Try some code. If it doesnt work, come here, post the code and show us what you tried and why it didnt work.

Comment: I think the downvotes were a bit too harsh here, especially considering the quality of the answer.  In a similar situation, I wrote this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127181/matching-images-with-different-orientations-and-scales-in-matlab/29128507#29128507 - where the OP didn't show much effort, but the question got highly upvoted as well as the answer.  To those who downvoted, you should consider removing the downvotes at least.  There's a clear double standard here that I don't like.

Comment: @rayryeng, IMHO, this question deserved a downvote, and still does. I could say the same about the other one, I can only assume it got most of the upvotes after your excellent answer. In my experience, a bad question often get a lot of undeserved upvotes, due to a great answer. IMO, the answer should be upvoted, not the question... Having said that, 8 downvotes seems a bit overkill. But then again, 8 downvotes mean 8 people thought it was bad, not that it's 8 times as bad as a post with only 1 downvote. Just my two cents...

Comment: And Shai: your answer is awesome! =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin - I'm inclined to agree with your comment.  I can see that now!

Comment: @StewieGriffin thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Consider this as a beginner's tutorial to Matlab image processing. Read the documentation of the commands used and try and **understand** what they are doing and why.

#### 1. Read the image

Use [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) to read the image into a 3D matrix. For convenience, we convert it to `double` in the range [0..1] using [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html):

```
>> img = im2double( imread( 'path/to/battety.jpg' ) );
```

You can check out the size of your `img` using [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) command:

```
>> size( img )
ans =
    1024         768           3
```

You can see from the result that your image has 1024 rows, 768 columns and 3 channels (Red, Green and Blue).

#### 2. Convert to black and white (a.k.a thresholding)

As you can see the battery is significantly brighter than the background and is colorless. We can select pixels that have large gap between the brightest channel value to darkest channel values as "battery" pixels:

```
>> bw = (max(img,[],3)-min(img,[],3)) > 0.2;
```

See [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) for more details.
There are other methods to threshold an image, see [`graythresh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) for more details.

Using [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html) we can see what we got:

```
>> imshow(bw,[],'border','tight');
```

[image]

Normally one uses [morphological operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-filtering.html) to improve thresholding results.
You can use [`imclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html):

```
>> bw = imclose( bw, ones(25) );
```

Resulting with:
[image]

#### 3. find angle of rotation

A *very* useful command for processing and working with bw images is [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html). It allows you to get all sorts of nice properties. You are going to use it to compute the [`'Orientation'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?searchHighlight=regionprops#inputarg_properties) of the "white"/battery region of your image

```
>> st = regionprops( bw, 'Orientation' )
st = 
Orientation: 52.8694
```

As you can see the battery is rotated by 52.8 degrees.
Using [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) to "straighten" the battery

```
>> rbw = imrotate( bw, -st.Orientation );
```

Once the battery is axis-aligned, you can "project" the white pixels onto the horizontal and vertical axes using [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html):

```
>> pc = any( rbw, 2 ); %// project all rows into a single column 
>> pr = any( rbw, 1 ); %// project all columns into a single row
```

Now you need to find the first and last pixels set to 1 in the projections. Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) for that:

```
>> fx = find( pr, 1, 'first');  %// first x coordinate
>> tx = find( pr, 1, 'last');   %// last x coordinat
>> fy = find( pc, 1, 'first');  %// first y coordinate
>> ty = find( pc, 1, 'last');   %// last y coordinate
```

Once you have x,y coordinates of corners, you can plot them on the rotated image:

```
>> imshow(rbw,[],'border','tight');
>> hold on; 
>> plot( [fx tx tx fx fx], [fy fy ty ty fy], ':r', 'LineWidth',3);
```

Yields:
[image]

And the coordinates are:

```
>> [fx fy tx ty]
ans =
406   608   866   733
```

As you can see your battery is (866-406) pixels long and (733-608) pixels wide.